# Find and alter text in a string based on ln # and character #

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I prepend characters to a word located at a particular Ln # and character # in text?

**Example:**

The use case is when a person enters code into a textarea (like jsFiddle), I find and replace some of their variables. I know the line # and character location of the start and end of these variables.

Example Text:

```
var usersCode = $('textarea').val();
```

console logging `usersCode`:

```
print "My first name is: " + first_name
print "This is awesome."
print "My last name is: " + last_name
```

How could I find the word starting at Ln 0, Char 29 and ending at Ln 0, Char 39 (first_name) and turn it into `MyObj.first_name.value`?

```
print "My first name is: " + MyObj.first_name.value
print "This is awesome."
print "My last name is: " + last_name
```

Maybe I can use a regex that translates "line number" into counting the number of `\n` occurrences? And then moving the pointer in by the number of characters?

I have to use Ln # and Char # for many details that I won't go into here. I am aware of many simpler alternatives if I wasn't constrained to using Ln # and Ch #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to replace `first_name` and `last_name` the simplest solution would be to use `replace()`, for example:

```
usersCode.replace("first_name", MyObj.first_name.value);
usersCode.replace("last_name", MyObj.last_name.value);
```

If you're insistent on doing the line number and character number specific thing, we can arrange that, but it's not at all necessary for what it seems like you're asking for. Perhaps I'm mistaken, though.

**Update:**

Okay so you want to replace all instances? Finding line numbers and all that is still unnecessary, just use this:

```
usersCode.replace(/first_name/g, MyObj.first_name.value);
usersCode.replace(/last_name/g, MyObj.last_name.value);
```

`g` is a RegEx flag for global searching.

**Update 2:**

```
usersCode.split("\n")[lineNumber - 1].replace(usersCode.split("\n")[lineNumber - 1].substr(29, 39), MyObj.first_name.value);
```

You can replace `29` and `39` with variables `startChar` and `endChar` respectively. `lineNumber` will also need to be provided by you.

Comment: There can be arbitrary text, so there may be many occurrences of `first_name`. There are many other complications that make using Ln # and Ch # a requirement. For example, I'm using CodeMirror instead of textarea... which means there are a lot of details about not using easier approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but no, I do not want to replace all instances. I only want to replace the instance at the particular line and character number.

Comment: if there is arbitrary text, that would indicate that you don't want to hard code line and character numbers. the customer's always right though, so give me two seconds.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not hard coding line numbers and chars, the user clicks on a variable name in their editor, and as an event handler I get the Ln # and Char # of the variable name... then switch it

Comment: Awesome sxnine - thanks for giving it a shot, I'll try it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the lines of the textarea into an array:

```
var lines = $('#textarea').val().split(/\n/);
```

And from there you take the substring of a particular line and assign it to your object:

```
MyObj.first_name.value = lines[0].substring(29,39)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

RegEx can easily search based on characters but not via position. Though you can still do it using regEx but the soultion will  become more and more complex. For this case you don;t need a pure RegEx answer. Code below  is what you need.

```
k=$('#regex_string').val()

function findAndReplaceWord(lineNo, startPos, endPos, replaceWith) {
    var line = k.split(/\n/)[lineNo];
    if(line) {
        var word = line.substring(startPos, endPos)

        return k.replace(word, replaceWith)
    }
}

findAndReplaceWord(0, 29, 39, MyObj.first_name.value)
```