# Javascript regex: get text at a particular line and character #

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a chunk of text (imagine a page from a book), how can I get the word at a particular line and character #?

Find and return the word at Ln # 3, Ch # 7 "just".

```
var text = "Lorem ispum dolar\n
Si emit I dont know latin\n
Really just making this up as I go\n
Ok this should be enough for us to work on.\n
```

JSFiddle to try code on: http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xS/709/

Comment: This is a simplification of another question about prepending & appending text at a location - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708110/find-and-alter-text-in-a-string-based-on-ln-and-character. This simplified question will be more searchable & consumable to the community. If it has the same answer, I will post it here and delete the other more specific question.

Comment: If you downvote a question, please leave a comment explaining why. Thanks

Comment: Can't you do this without Regex, using: `(text.split("\n")[line_number-1]).substring(character_number-1);`?

Comment: Hmm gave it a shot Max - doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xS/707/

Comment: http://regex101.com/#javascript <-- should work better than a fiddle in this case ;)

Comment: @Donny P Strangely, I can't even do `example_text.split("\n");`... Maybe I'm too tired to see the real issue, but you got my point, sort of. EDIT: Forgot to make the result a single character too, haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this `(?:.*\n){2}.{6}\s+(\w+)` Where this would get word of line 2+1 starting at character 6+1.

Edit: Figured I'd robustify it a bit. The above fails to match anything if you provide a character-index in the middle of a word. The following will skip ahead untill the start of a word before it starts capturing: `(?:.*\n){2}.{6}.*?\b(\w+)\b`.

PS: Regex in javascript doesn't support positive lookbehind, so skipping back to the start of the word is quite a bit trickier.

Edit2: Making the string.replace work requires us to capture the other parts of the string. This seems to do the trick: `text.replace(/((?:.*\n){2}(?:.{6}.*?))\b(\w+)\b((?:.*\n?)*)/g, "$1[the-replacement]$3")` but it does complicate things. It might be better to use the more direct approach in this case. Simplicity is king!

Comment: +1, we're indeed having a mind-meld, and you're right that `.*` works just as well as `[^\r\n]`

Comment: Thanks Mithon (and zx81) for the help. Accepted the answer. @Mithon I'm also trying to replace the matched text using your `.replace()` comment, but it seems to replace all text before the match as well: http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xS/711/

Comment: See Edit2 for a solution with the string.replace approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.example_text = "Lorem ispum dolar\n\
Si emit I dont know latin\n\
Really just making this up as I go\n\
Ok this should be enough for us to work on.\n";

var lineNumber = 3;
var charNumber = 7;

var match = (example_text.split("\n")[lineNumber - 1]).substr(charNumber).split(/\s/)[0];
console.log(match);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DFhM/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
^(?:.*(?:\r?\n)*){2}.{6}\W+(\w+)
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- To get to line 3, we need to skip two lines
- Our line skipper is `(?:.*(?:\r?\n)*){2}`, matching any chars that are not line breaks, then line breaks
- `.{6}` eats up the first six chars
- There is no word starting at character 7, so we are going to match the next word:
- `\W+` matches any non-word chars
- `(\w+)` captures word chars to Group 1
- we retrieve the match from Group 1

In JS:

```
var myregex = /^(?:.*[\r\n]*){2}.{6}\W+(\w+)/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[1];
} else {
    thematch = "";
}
```

Comment: FYI Made small tweak and added explanation. :)

Comment: Note that the `\r?\n` looks longer, but it allows for both Windows-style line breaks `\r\n` and Unix style `\n`

Comment: Glad it works, Donny. :) Yes, to add these words, just replace the match line with `thematch = "MyMatch." + matchArray[1] + ".value"` to concatenate the string. :)

Comment: You can replace the first [^\r\n] block with a simple `.*` since the non-capturing group it's part of will match the linebreaks greedily. Therefore there is no possibility of that segment containing a linebreak.

Comment: Oh sorry my comment wasn't clear, I meant in the actual text I want to replace it with the "MyMatch." + matchArray[1] + ".value".

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, the `[\r\n]` is the first thing that came out of my mind, normally I tweak my regexps but I didn't want to look like I was lifting the `.*` from you. :) Since you're okay with it, I'll substitute it. And +1 for your answer.

Comment: You can use `yourstring.replace(myregex, "My replacement $1 here")` instead to build your new string.

Comment: Totally fine with it. I just wanna help :)

Comment: Your [regex](http://regex101.com/r/eW6lC8/1) takes more steps then @mithon [regex](http://regex101.com/r/eW6lC8/2) as illustrated by regex debugger link and there is huge difference in steps.

Comment: Sure, after the match you can just replace the whole variable with `mystring = "MyMatch." + matchArray[1] + ".value"` :)

Comment: @Braj FYI the only debugger I would trust is the one in RegexBuddy... Or even better when using PCRE, straight to the source with `pcretest` Also the `\r?\n` is needed to allow for various kinds of linebreaks.

Comment: @Mithon - trying `yourstring.replace(...)` but it seems to cut off everything before the match as well: http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xS/711/ -

Comment: You don't need to use `yourstring.replace`. Just `yourstring = "MyMatch." + matchArray[1] + ".value"`

Comment: Agreed. You can use the straight-forward way. But if you want to do more fancy stuff, the replacement way can be usefull. If you want to keep the unmatched parts you need to reference them in the replacement string. See the MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late now lol, lots of good answers but here goes for the sake of completeness:

made this regexp here: http://regex101.com/r/nF2vX8/1

`(?:.*\n.*){2}^(?:.{7})(\w*\W)`

and here's a solution in javascript:

```
var index_left = 0, index_right = 0, stringy = "";
for (; line_number-- > 0;){
    index_left = index_right;
    index_right = example_text.indexOf("\n", index_right) + 1;
}

stringy = example_text.substring(index_left, index_right-1);

index_left = 0;
index_left = stringy.indexOf(" ", char_number+1);
stringy = stringy.substring(0, index_left);
index_left = stringy.lastIndexOf(" ", index_left);
stringy = stringy.substring(index_left+1);

console.log(stringy);
```

and the fiddle for the js: http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xS/714/

it mangles `line_number` but it's easy to fix by copying the value and i'm too bored to do it now :P